# Is it possible to edit part inside assembly simultaneously seeing an assembly or some of it?

Tags: solidworks

I would like to design a part, matching other parts of an assembly and I don't want to remember sizes. Can I just restrict editing to some part and/ or create new part from within existing assembly?

Comment: The simple answer to this question is “yes”. The complex answer is “yes, in several ways, the most appropriate of which is impossible to determine without more details of what you are trying to make, and how interlinked the components are to be, or how flexible the assembly needs to be. (A multi body part may well be better).

Answer (score 0):

You can edit one component while in assembly mode. Just select the desired component, then click "Edit Component". If you alter an mating surfaces you'll have to go through and renew the mates reference surfaces.

To create a new part within the assembly, you can select insert components->new part. That will insert a blank part you can then edit as desired.